# Writing table to specific folder

Tags: matlab, save, export-to-excel

I am wondering how one can save a table using the following

```
 filename_excel = [ name '_N' num2str(1) '.xlsx'];
 writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', 3, 'Range','A5');
```

to a specific directory/folder other than the current folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change filename_excel to

```
filename_excel = [my_directory name '_N' num2str(1) '.xlsx'];
```

where

```
my_directory = 'C:\some\directory\structure\';
```

Alternatively (though use the first solution if possible) you can go:

```
current_dir = cd;
cd my_directory;

filename_excel = [ name '_N' num2str(1) '.xlsx'];
writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', 3, 'Range','A5');

cd current_dir;
clear current_dir;
```

Comment: Are you sure `my_directory` and `name` should not be concatenated? The [filename](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html#inputarg_filename) argument of [writetable](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) indicates that they should.

Comment: For the first solution my_directory is placed into the filename_excel char array. writetable only sees the complete char array, so it treats it as if you put `writetable(Table,'C:\some\directory\structure\name_N1.xlsx','Sheet', 3, 'Range','A5');`.

Comment: I am referring to the first suggestion. Could you show the output, please because the documentation says `filename` should be a string. Not an array.

Comment: @kkuilla, the `[ ... ]` **is** a concatenation operator. Otherwise good solution. I would highlight the first method as _recommended_ (versus the second one. Avoid changing the current directory if you can afford to do it otherwise).

Comment: @Hoki Oh, dear... How could I forget that. Apologies. I agree. The first solution is the preferred one. +1.

Comment: @Hoki, added, the first solution is definitely better.

Comment: @Ayb4btu Thanks a lot. For sure the first method is definitely is keen one.